# react controlled textarea how to format

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to build a markdown previewer by react. I have a controlled textarea where the value is from the state. is there a way to show the format data in the preview? Currently, if I enter in a new line, the preview will not reflect that.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
     this.state = {
      input: 'Enter some text'
      }
     this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
   handleChange (event) {

    this.setState({

      input: event.target.value

    })

  }
  render() {
    return <div>
           <textarea id="editor" onChange={this.handleChange}>{this.state.input}</textarea>
           <section id="preview">
           {this.state.input}
           </section>  
           </div>
    
  }
  
  
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add CSS property `white-space: pre-wrap;` to the `preview` section. It will reflect the new line (pressing enter inside the `textarea`)

Ref: [white-space property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

Working example: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-cdn-wv090q?file=/src/styles.css&resolutionWidth=320&resolutionHeight=675)